# Is there a in-built voice in gstreamer?

Tags: linux, audio, gstreamer, gtk3

I am building a `gtk+3.0` application. When a user clicks a button or enters information, I want to give audio feedback to the user using `gstreamer`.

Is there an in-built voice, which, when a string is passed to it, it speaks the string?
If yes, are there culture-specific voices?
Are different languages supported in such a in-built voice?

Or should i just ask someone to let me record their voice for each audio feedback that has to be provided? This will be inefficient if the application grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the 'festival' plugin, it uses the festival library but doesn't have any configuration properties. If you find out the the festival library can have properties exposed that are useful for you please request them to be added in gstreamer bugzilla: http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer